# Criar super usuario no django rest

Tags: python, api, django, django-rest-framework

Gostaria de saber como posso criar um super usuario no django rest framework, sei que posso usar o comando:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

mas como posso fazer isso como uma request POST? e como eu poderia diferenciar esse super usuário de um usuario comum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira simples de resolver o problema é criando um `endpoint` para um cadastro de um novo usuário.

Neste exemplo vou criar um novo usuário através de um endpoint, este novo usuário que estou criando é do tipo User (o mesmo tipo utilizado pelo `django-admin`). Vou utilizar o fluxo sugerido pela arquitetura padrão do `django-rest-framework`

Serão algumas etapas que vou descrever os passos:

1. Criar uma classe serializer para o tipo `User` (uma abstração de um DTO)
2. Criar uma APIView para o model `User` (uma abstração de um service)
3. Criar uma rota para a criação de um novo usuário (uma abstração de um controller)

Desta forma, seguindo a ordem das operações acima, para criar um serializer para a classe User, basta criar um novo arquivo pela convenção do Django-rest-framework, possui o nome de ***serializers.py***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['password'] = make_password(validated_data.get('password'))
        return super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Ao criar o serializer, devemos sobre-escrever o método create. Isso é necessário para não gravar a senha em texto claro no banco de dados(com o auxílio da função [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/), primeira ocorrência), essa função vai gerar um hash do atributo password que é enviado na requisição. Após fazer o hash do atributo senha, é que salvamos o nosso modelo no banco de dados.

Com a lógica do serializer escrito podemos criar a nossa View, que vai ser a camada de serviço da nossa aplicação, ela vai servir para desacoplar o modelo da camada de apresentação.

***views.py***

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):
    model = User
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Repare que estou utilizando classes de `permissions` para que se a sua aplicação utiliza algum middleware de autenticação, esta rota seja pública. Ou seja, possível de ser chamada sem a necessidade de autenticação. Estamos utilizando a classe `UserSerializer` criada no passo anterior.

Agora basta criar a rota, para que seja possível criar um novo usuário, neste exemplo vou chamar esta rota de `cadastro`. Para isso vou criar uma nova rota no arquivo `urls.py` e importar a classe `CreateUserView`.

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .views import CreateUserView

urlpatterns = [
    path('cadastro', csrf_exempt(CreateUserView.as_view())),
]
```

Repare que aqui, estou fazendo uso da função `csrf_exempt`, pois o Django por padrão possui a proteção para csrf ativada. Neste caso eu estou explicitamente deixando esta rota sem a proteção csrf.

Esse seriam os passos essenciais para o que precisa.

Depois para poder fazer um cadastro, basta que seja feito uma requisição `post` na rota cadastro, use sua ferramenta favorita:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/cadastro -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": "usuario" ,"email":"a@b.com","password": "stackoverflowPT"}'
```

O que diferencia um `super usuário` de um usuário comum é um atributo `is_superuser` que é do tipo booleano. Quando você cria um objeto do tipo [django.contrib.auth.models.User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/) basta setar este atributo para True.

Comment: eu posso sobescrever os campos que ele da por padrão (username, email e password) ? eu queria cadastrar com cpf, telefone, senha.

Comment: Sim é possível, o que vai precisar fazer é herdar sua classe de  `AbstractBaseUser` depois criar os atributos, tem um exemplo de implementação [aqui](https://github.com/danizavtz/tutorialdjango/blob/master/eventex/myauth/models.py) @Leanz

Comment: depois de cadastrar um usuario e tentar entrar no admin de django recebo a seguinte mensagem: 
"Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."
porem o usuario e senha estão corretos

Comment: Sim isso é verdade, o atributo `is_staff` deve possuir o valor `True` para o usuário poder se logar via o django-admin. Esse atributo possuir o valor verdadeiro é necessário para poder se logar no django-admin. Segue a documentação que possui esta [declaração](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/), procurar por is_staff.

Comment: @JoséGuilhermeLins, assim se precisa que o usuário se logue no django-admin,  basta setar o atributo `is_staff` para possuir o valor True.